# Call WCF service in Windows service

Tags: wcf

My application has WCF service hosted in IIS. I have another application which is running through Windows service. Now i need to consume IIS Service (WCF with wsHTTPBinding) in the windows service.

I tried by creating proxy in windows service, but the it was not regognised by the windows service.

Can any one help me out with sample code by, how to call WCF service hosted in IIS from Windows service.

I attached the error information
[image]

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.IService1")]
public interface IService1 {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse")]
    string GetData(int value);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface IService1Channel : FileMgntService.ServiceReference1.IService1, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class Service1Client : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<FileMgntService.ServiceReference1.IService1>, FileMgntService.ServiceReference1.IService1 {

    public Service1Client() {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public Service1Client(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public string GetData(int value) {
        return base.Channel.GetData(value);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value) {
        return base.Channel.GetDataAsync(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried, and clarify what you mean by "it was not recognized by the windows service".  There should be no issue calling a WCF service from a Windows Service.

Comment: I got the above error in Referance.cs file

Comment: Please post the actual error not a picture, not everyone can view images from work

Comment: Iam getting error in "FileMgntService.ServiceReference1.IService1". The type name 'ServiceReferance1' doesn't exist in the type FileMgntService.